# PHPMYADMIN export truncates the text field for MYSQL database

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

In MYSQL table, there is a Text field which contains the below contents.

```
- Pedal car with high carbon steel frame in fade resistant powder coat finish- Synthetic rubberized wheels for a smooth, low- noise ride- Safety features include oversized anti- slip pedals, dual rear wheel hand brake and fully enclosed chain guard- 3 position easy adjust high- back racing seat and sporty steering wheel- Coasting shifter&lt;/p&gt; - 125102342ETCF4Y
```

But when i export the field that last few words are truncating. Please let me know why PHPMYADMIN export truncating these characters

```
- Pedal car with high carbon steel frame in fade resistant powder coat finish- Synthetic rubberized wheels for a smooth, low- noise ride- Safety features include oversized anti- slip pedals, dual rear wheel hand brake and fully enclosed chain guard- 3 pos
```

Comment: What type of export? there are multiple ways to export in PMA.

Comment: Export option present in phpmyadmin.  I noticed when i export the text field only 255 characters are exporting

Comment: I am exporting as Character set as UTF-8

Comment: Please see the answers below. What is your db column data type?

Comment: The field declared as Text

Comment: When i export UTF-16 the entire text field is exporting. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: When i export UTF-16 the entire text field is exporting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using CHAR, VARCHAR, or TINYTEXT you have a 255 character limit. You're going to want a different db column type potentially.

EDIT:

I also found this: [Why is the PHPMyAdmin import truncating text fields in some of my UPDATEs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11477084/why-is-the-phpmyadmin-import-truncating-text-fields-in-some-of-my-updates)

Try changing your import encoding from UTF-8 to ANSI.

Answer (score 0):

Could that be a TINYTEXT field, limited to a maximum of 256 characters?

Reference:

```
[https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/storage-requirements.html][1]
```

Comment: It's actually limited to 255, not 256.